# Find the column index when the value of character for the first time and last time in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame which looks like this

```
 a <- as.data.frame(c(1,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

I want to find the column indexes where for every row when it was `1` for the first time and last time
eg: for row `a` it is `2,10`

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
x <- df==1
rbind(max.col(x, "first"), max.col(x, "last"))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    2    1    1    1    2    3    3    2    2     4
#[2,]    2    6    6    4    4    5    6    6    2     6
```

OR with `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) c(min(which(x==1)),max(which(x==1))))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), c = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0), d = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), e = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1), f = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```